# Orthographic projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find the matrix of a generic orthographic projection onto a given plane $A$ that passes at the origin and the n-vector as the normal vector to the plane.

I only found matrices related to clipping planes, can anyone give me a general matrix for the case described above ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The operation "project onto the (hyper)plane $A$" can be done as follows:
$$\pi(x) = x-(v\cdot x)v$$
where $v$ is one of the two unit normal vectors to $A$. This operation is linear, and thus it has an expression as a matrix. In fact:
$$\pi(x)_i = x_i - v_jx_jv_i$$
(with summation over repeated indices) and thus we see that the matrix corresponding to the projection $\pi$ is:
$$P_{ij}=\delta_{ij}-v_iv_j$$
or:
$$P = 1-vv^T$$

Comment: Excuse my math dumbness, but what's $\delta_{i,j}$ ?

Comment: @cifz: $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta; $\delta_{i,j}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{i,j}=0$ if $i \neq j$.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that $v$ is a vector-column and $1$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

First find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by vectors $v_1,v_2,n$ so that $v_1\perp n$ and $v_2\perp n$. Then the change of basis matrix is given by the matrix with column vectors $v_1,v_2,$ and $n$, $A=(v_1,v_2,n)$. Once in this basis, the projection matrix is
$$ P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Now change back to the standard basis. That is, the projection matrix is $A^{-1}PA$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to obtain the basis as I do not really have $\hat{n}$ really.